# Source code in header files

Tags: c++, c

Is it bad if I include source code in a header file (like to define functions, classes, etc.)? I've read that it's not recommended, but also that it's perfectly fine to do this... is there a right answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you include source code in a header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588727/should-you-include-source-code-in-a-header-file)

Comment: You want to define your classes and functions within header files thats what they're for. In general you implement your classes and functions in .c files.

Comment: The main advantage of header-only libraries is that they avoid all the work and hassle of building the binaries of a library. For example, for a typical header-only sub-library of Boost you only need to set the include path and off you go. For other sub-libraries, building Boost can be very time consuming, difficult to get right.

Comment: The main advantage of separate compilation is that it provides a strong decoupling, called a "compiler firewall". Headers used by implementation files will not contribute to the compile time of  your headers, and will not introduce all kinds of undesired stuff (that client code may come to depend on).

Comment: you should write code in headers in C++ when you are using `templates`

Answer (score 1):

Functions which are not marked as `inline` cannot go in headers because if they get included twice in your program, the linker will give you an error. Note that methods inside classes are treated as inline.

As long as you only use templates and inline code, you can put your code in a header. But then it gets compiled once *for each* source file you have that includes it, slowing down the build. You can counteract this with a precompiled header, and then the only real disadvantage is a lack of good 'partial' building, but the build overall performs decently.

So it really boils down to just compile time and I think precompiled headers can mostly counter the negative effects. But I still prefer proper source files a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1):

One case where common non-inline functions are coded in a common header is for a multi-processing (as opposed to multi-threading) application. The code for each process has one source file that includes the common header with those common functions.